# Why does Typescript think async/await returns a value wrapped in a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-2017

I want to refactor a promise chain into async/await, but Typescript is complaining about the typing.

> TS2322:Type 'IHttpPromiseCallbackArg< IResp >' is not assignable to type 'IResp'...

<s>I thought `await` would return a regular value, not a promise. Am I wrong? If so, how can I assign a typing so that the desired code will compile?</s>

I thought await would return the same value as the first argument in the .then callback. Am I wrong?

Old code:

```
handleSubmit(form) {
    const params = this.getParams(form);

    this.myAsyncRequest(params)
       .then((resp:IResp) => this.processResp(resp))
       .catch((e:IServerError) => this.handleError(e));
 }
```

Desired new code:

```
async handleSubmit(form) {
    const params = this.getParams(form);

    try {
        const resp:IResp = await this.myAsyncRequest(params); //typing error with "const resp:IResp"
        this.processResp(resp);
    } catch (e:IServerError) {
        this.handleError(e);
    }
}
```

The desired code still breaks if I remove the return type in `myAsyncRequest` ; I guess Typescript infers  directly from the AngularJS library.

```
myAsyncRequest(params:IParams):IHttpPromise<IResp> {
    return $http.post('blah', data);
}
```

If I remove "IResp" from the const resp declaration, processResponse complains that IHttp< IResp> does not equal IResp...

```
processResp(resp:IResp) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: The type IHttpPromiseCallbackArg is not a promise. This is already the actual result of the function call. See http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angular-translate--angular-translate/interfaces/ng.ihttppromisecallbackarg.html

Comment: I can reword my question to - "I thought `await` would return the same value as the first argument in the `.then` callback. Am I wrong?"

Comment: You are correct. But you are wrong about what the type of the first parameter in the then callback function is. See http://definitelytyped.org/docs/angularjs--angular-route/interfaces/ng.ihttppromise.html

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong type definition for what you are actually using. But we need a full working example to say that definitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question "I thought await would return the same value as the first argument in the .then callback. Am I wrong?".

No, you are absolutely right. But you are wrong about what the first argument in the .then callback is.

You define `myAsyncRequest` to return `IHttpPromise<IResp>`. But `IHttpPromise<T>` is defined as inheriting `IPromise` the following way:

```
type IHttpPromise<T> = IPromise<IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>>;
```

So, an `IHttpPromise<T>` is a promise that returns an `IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>` back where the actual data of type `T` is in the `data` property of the `IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>`.

So, the old code variant we see in the question:

```
handleSubmit(form) {
    const params = this.getParams(form);

    this.myAsyncRequest(params)
       .then((resp:IResp) => this.processResp(resp))
       .catch((e:IServerError) => this.handleError(e));
 }
```

should actually not compile without errors in TypeScript when `myAsyncRequest` is defined to return `IHttpPromise`.

Howto fix this:

```
async handleSubmit(form) {
    const params = this.getParams(form);

    try {
        const httpResp:IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IResp> = await this.myAsyncRequest(params); 
        const resp: IResp = httpResp.data;
        this.processResp(resp);
    } catch (e:IServerError) {
        this.handleError(e);
    }
}
```

---

Note: In the latest type definitions for angular, the type `IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>` is actually called `IHttpResponse<T>`.

Maybe in your code, you have defined `IResp` as `IHttpResponse<Something>`? Then you just have a conflict with the old name `IHttpPromiseCallbackArg`. Then get the newest type definitions from DefinitelyTyped that uses the new name. And you would also have to change the definition of `myAsyncRequest` to:

```
myAsyncRequest(params:IParams):IHttpPromise<Something> {
```

Answer (score 0):

The line containing the `await` does indeed await the resolved value - but because the function itself is async (to allow all that awaiting), you get back a promise.

Example... in the below code you can use `x` as a plain number (even though `delay` returns a promise) and again for `y` - so all the stuff you await is resolved so you can use it more like you would if it were synchronous.

The async function that doesn't look like it returns a promise, now does.

This can seem confusing, because it seems to "invert the promises", but what it does is shift the `then` to the top level (you could have async functions calling down to other async functions and so on).

```
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise<number>(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(5);
        }, ms);
    });
}


async function asyncAwait() {
    let x = await delay(1000);
    console.log(x);

    let y = await delay(1000);
    console.log(y);

    return 'Done';
}

asyncAwait().then((result) => console.log(result));
```

Comment: So at the end of the day, I still have to call `.then` somewhere?

Comment: You _may_ still have to call `then` at the very top (in some cases, where you are passing your function to something else, you won't have to).

Comment: What's with the downvote? Any recommendations for improving the answer?

Comment: This does not answer the question which seems to be a misunderstanding about the types the function returns. The type IHttpPromiseCallbackArg is not a promise as the questioner assumes.

Comment: I was attempting to answer the question "I thought await would return a regular value, not a promise. Am I wrong?'